# Mocking dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, magicmock

I am Python newbie and trying to understand how to mock methods in UTs.

Here is my Test
**test_module2.py**

```
from module2 import A
import unittest

from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

class TestBulkLoad(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('simple_module.SimpleModuleClass')
    def test_fun(self, a):
        a.simpleFun = MagicMock(return_value=3)

        testA = A()
        testA.fun()

        assert a.simpleFun.called
```

and I want to check that dependent `SimpleModuleClass` was mocked and invoked

**module2.py**

```
from simple_module import SimpleModuleClass


class A:
    def fun(self):
        print('I am from A class')

        thing = SimpleModuleClass()
        thing.simpleFun()

        return -1
```

**simple_module.py**

```
class SimpleModuleClass:
    def simpleFun(self):
        print("I am from SimpleModuleClass")
        return 0
```

I get AssertionError. Could you help me understand how to fix this?

Comment: What is it printing? Would you change `testA.fun()` to `r = testA.fun()` and then `self.assertEqual(3, r)` (in order to test the return value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.simpleFun = MagicMock(return_value=3)`

This line is only modifying the method of your mock object `a` (which you really should rename `simpleModuleMock`, since it's a mock of a `SimpleModule` class and not an `A`). It doesn't mock every instance of `SimpleModule` everywhere in your code, hence why an instance of `SimpleModule` is instantiated in `A.fun()` and not an instance of a mock of `SimpleModule`.

I would use dependency injection and pass an instance of `SimpleModule` to `A.fun()` instead of instantiating it inside of it, so that you can pass a mock. You could also make `thing` a public variable like so:

**test_module2.py**:

```
class TestBulkLoad(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('simple_module.SimpleModuleClass')
    def test_fun(self, simpleModuleMock):
        simpleModuleMock.simpleFun = MagicMock(return_value=3)

        testA = A()
        A.thing = simpleModuleMock
        assert(testA.fun() == -1)

        # assert simpleModule.simpleFun.called
        assert isinstance(simpleModuleMock.simpleFun, MagicMock)
```

**module2.py**:

```
class A:
    thing = SimpleModuleClass()
    def fun(self):
        print('I am from A class')
        self.thing.simpleFun()
        return -1
```

Note that there may exist better solutions with Python, but if there are, 1. I don't know of them, and 2. I doubt they're good practice.